# Replaykit stopRecording shows black screen iOS 12

Tags: ios, service, view, terminate, replaykit

After updating to iOS 12 release version on Sept 18, 2018 - I see that my app with replaykit shows black screen instead of a RPPreviewViewController after stopRecording is called. I present the previewController in stopRecording. The log shows -

`2018-09-17 18:11:35.350134+0530 Anivy - Voice Changer[558:46391] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}`

This was not an issue in iOS 11. This issue also exist in iOS 12.1 beta 1. 
Not only my app, but also i used a game from the app store which implemented replaykit for recording screen and it was also doing the same when the recording is stopped. The app/game goes useless after that.

I searched the internet from last 10-12 days and tried everything but the issue still remains and occurs sometimes.

Any help would be appreciated. Is anyone else seeing the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. iOS 12.1

Comment: You're not alone!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551482/ios-12-replaykit-is-broken  I also have the same issue.